# Divide Column in Half in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

using BigQuery, I would like to be able to divide one column, column1, into two separate columns, column2, and column3 with 50% of all records in column1 in column2 and 50% of all records in column1 in column 3. Ex column1 has 8 records of the number 2. I'd like to create a column2 with 4 records of the number 2 and column3 with 4 records of the number 2.

Is there a query to write this in BigQuery?

| Column1 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

| Column2 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

| Column3 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

Comment: when you say you want to break a column in 2 different columns, do you mean you want the 3 columns in the same result or only column 2 and 3 in the result (without columns 1)? or column 2 and 3 as 2 separate results?

Comment: @99_m4n column 2 and column 3 as two separate results/tables is preferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```sql
SELECT
  Column1 AS Column2
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
WHERE 1=1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) <= (
  SELECT COUNT(*)/2
  FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
);
SELECT
  Column1 AS Column3
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
WHERE 1=1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) > (
  SELECT COUNT(*)/2
  FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
);
```

This will give you 2 results: One for each Column2 and Column3 with the first and second half of the data respectively **order by Column1** (to use analytical functions you always have to specify an `ORDER BY` inside an `OVER` clause)

For random order try:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE a AS (
  SELECT Column1 as Column2
  FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
  WHERE 1=1
  QUALIFY
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) <= (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`)
);
SELECT Column1 as Column3
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
WHERE Column1 NOT IN (SELECT * FROM a);
SELECT * FROM a
```

In this case you'll get 3 results: first one is the temporary table creation and the other 2 are the columns 2 and 3.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is EXACTLY the output I needed thank you for saving my day!!

Comment: Quick question...if I wanted the results randomized in column2 or column3 vs ordering by Column1 would I use the rand() function?

Comment: I edited the answer to also get the columns in random order