# Joining Two Tables in BigQuery Without Common Column and Different Amount of Rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a table in BigQuery by joining two tables without a common column and differing row totals. Please help me update the query below or let me know if the logic doesn't make sense.

Table 1 = 180M rows
Table 2 = 65M rows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `myproject.mydataset_joinedtable` AS
(SELECT 
t1.column1 AS column1
t2.column2 AS column2
t1.column3 AS column3
t1.column4 AS column4

FROM `myproject.mydataset_table1` t1,`myproject.mydataset_table2` t2):
```

Comment: Can you craft smaller sample input tables, able to represent your current situation, and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: You can create a row_number in both tables and join by this column. For row_number, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254631/divide-column-in-half-in-bigquery  `Select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) as row_id from myproject.mydataset_table1 ) left join  (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column3) as row_id  from myproject.mydataset_table2) using(row_id)`